# How to compare numpy strings in Python 3

Tags: python, string, numpy, comparison

The following demonstrates the problem:

```
import io
import numpy as np

a = np.loadtxt(io.StringIO("val1 val2\nval3 val4"), \
               dtype=np.dtype([("col1", "S10"), ("col2", "S10")]))
print("looks weired: %s"%(a["col1"][0]))
assert(a["col1"][0] == "val1")
```

I don't understand how I should compare the strings. On my system (numpy 1.6.2, python 3.2.2) the output looks like this:

```
>>> 
looks weired: b'val1'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/..../bug_sample.py", line 7, in <module>
    assert(a["col1"][0] == "val1")
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not `numpy`-related:

```
>>> b"asd" == "asd"
False
```

In Python 3 `bytes` objects don't compare equal to `string`s. So either:

- compare against `b"val1"` instead of `"val1"` so that the types match,
- decode the `bytes` object into a string (like `.decode('utf-8')` and compare with `"val1"`.

Comment: Thanks Kos, but why is the value returned as a byte array if it is declared "S10"? I would expect it to be a np.str. The behavoir of numpy is not intuitive.

Comment: That depends on your intuition. :-) Maybe they just didn't want the typestrings to change meaning in Python 3. See also  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html#arrays-interface

Comment: Kos, I am new to py3k so maybe I oversee something fundamental... but the result of this simply looks wrong: a = np.loadtxt(io.StringIO("val1 val2\nval3 val4"), dtype=np.dtype([("col1", np.str, 4), ("col2", "S4")]))
print(a)